# Windowing feature Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, accelerometer

I'm new to Matlab and trying to Window the features of a signal from an accelerometer into a txt file. However I am getting the wrong data and cannot see where the error is in my code.I would be grateful if anyone could spot the error for me.

```
        %WindowParams
Fq = 51.2;
%Sample Rate of Shimmer
windowLength = 15;
%Length for each window in seconds
startPos = 1;
startPos2 = 1;
startPos3 = 1;
%Starting Position for 1st win
endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
endPos2 = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
endPos3= startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
%End Position for 1st win
totalWindows = floor(length(martySit)/Fq/windowLength);
totalWindows2 = floor(length(martyJump)/Fq/windowLength);
totalWindows3 = floor(length(martyRun)/Fq/windowLength);
stats = zeros(windowLength,9);
for i = 1:totalWindows
    epMean = mean(martySit(startPos:endPos,:));
    %calculate window mean
    %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
    martySitfeatures (i,2:5) = epMean;
    %Next window position
    startPos = endPos+1;
    endPos = startPos + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
    martySitfeatures (:,5) = 1;
end
for i = 1:totalWindows2
    epMean = mean(martyJump(startPos2:endPos2,:));
    %calculate window mean
    %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
    martyJumpfeatures (i,2:5) = epMean;
    %Next window position
    startPos2 = endPos2+1;
    endPos2 = startPos2 + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
    martyJumpfeatures (:,5) = 2;
end
for i = 1:totalWindows3
    epMean = mean(martyRun(startPos3:endPos3,:));
    %calculate window mean
    %X, Y & Z axis values for each stat
    martyRunfeatures (i,2:5) = epMean;
    %Next window position
    startPos3 = endPos3+1;
    endPos3 = startPos3 + (windowLength * floor(Fq));
    martyRunfeatures (:,5) = 3;
end
```

The results look like this when I save them to a file which I don't think is right

```
 0.0000000e+00   8.0683900e+03  -5.2872114e-01  -4.4968032e+00   1.0000000e+00
   0.0000000e+00   8.0879213e+03  -5.2027124e-01  -4.4780305e+00   1.0000000e+00
   0.0000000e+00   1.3087921e+04  -5.7103067e-01  -4.5288128e+00   1.0000000e+00
   0.0000000e+00   4.0041046e+04   8.8934563e+00   8.1063856e-01   2.0000000e+00
   0.0000000e+00   2.4044953e+04   9.4689311e+00   9.0349316e-01   3.0000000e+00
```

Comment: What kind of output would you expect ?

Comment: I would expect there to be 3 rows for 1.0000000e+00, 3 rows for 2.0000000e+00 and 3 rows for 3.0000000e+00. Or just 1 row for 1.0000000e+00, 1 row for 2.0000000e+00 and 1 row for 3.0000000e+00. Also the first column should calculate the mean from the following 3 columns in that row but it is just giving me 0.